# Definition of limit in general metric spaces

Tags: limits, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

> Let $(Z,d), (Y,d')$ be metric spaces, $a$ a limit point of $X$ in $Z$.
>   Let $X \subset Z, b \in Y$ and $f: X \to Y$ be a function. We then say
>   that:
>
> $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = b \iff  \forall \epsilon > 0:\exists\delta >
>  0: \forall x \in B_Z(a, \delta)\cap(X \setminus\{a\}): f(x) \in B_Y(b,
>  \epsilon)$$

As far as I know, it is possible that $a \notin X$. For example, consider the set $\{n^{-1}\mid n \in \mathbb{N}_0\}$ which has the limit point $0$ in the real numbers.

Then, what does the notation $X \setminus\{a\}$ mean? Isn't set complement only defined for subsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set complement $X \setminus U$ means $\{x \in X \mid x \not \in U\}$. It is *not* neccessary for $U$ to be a subset of $X$. 
In your case, if $a \not \in X$, $X \setminus \{a\}$ simply equals $X$.